# How to prevent NVIDIA drivers from automatically upgrading on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I was training models last night on my Ubuntu workstation, and then woke up this morning and saw this message:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

Apparently the NVIDIA system driver automatically updated itself, and now I need to reboot the machine to use my GPUs... How do I prevent automatic updates from NVIDIA?

Comment: not sure why people want to close this. Is the solution obvious? If not, perhaps you should leave some feedback!

Comment: I think your question is essential and not worth closing. Could you please mark my solution as accepted if it solved your issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If this is because of unattended upgrades (likely), then you should add the NVIDIA drivers to it's blacklist. Add `nvidia-` and `libnvidia-` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` like so:

```py
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
        "nvidia-";
        "libnvidia-";
        ...
}
```

Consider adding additional lines if you see any other NVIDIA driver names in the output of `apt list --installed | grep nv`

Comment: I have a media server with the nvidia-container-runtime for docker as well as nvenc/nvdec. All my nvidia package names matches the regex `^(lib)?nvidia-`. As well as some `linux-*-nvidia-*` packages already covered by default unattended-upgrades rules.

Comment: @snake_case how do you know `linux-*-nvidia-*` is already blacklisted ? It doesn't appear in my `50unattended-upgrades` file. Thanks !

Comment: In the default blacklist, the "linux-" prefix is included but commented out. I must have uncommented that myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have had the same issue. It is because of so-called unattended upgrades on Ubuntu.

## Solution 1: check the changed packages and revert the updates

Check the apt history logs

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Then you can see what packages have changed. Use `apt` or `aptitude` to revert the changes.

## Solution 2: disable unattended upgrades

Use [this](https://linuxhint.com/enable-disable-unattended-upgrades-ubuntu/) guide to disable unattended upgrades. Please consider if this solution works for you as you have to install security updates manually after this change.

## Solution 3: hold specific packages

Use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) guide on how to hold certain packages. Read the apt history as mentioned above to determine which packages you have to put on hold. Probably CUDA related packages such as `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. Hard to say since some information is missing from your post. You can see all nvidia related packages like this

```
dpkg -l *nvidia*
```

I hope at least one of my solutions works for you :)

P.S. you have to change the title. NVIDIA isn't upgrading anything on your system by itself. Ubuntu is the one causing your trouble ;)

Comment: The better solution instead of disabling unattended upgrades altogether would be to add the NVIDIA packages to your unattended upgrades blacklist file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Comment: @RVRX sounds like a good solution for unattended upgrades exactly.

Answer (score -1):

If you check your `/var/log/dpkg.log`, you will find it auto upgrades your `nvidia*` and `libnvidia*` packages in the early morning, as shown in the screenshots. A more aggressive way to disable this is to `sudo apt remove unattended-upgrades` [Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322292/how-do-i-turn-off-automatic-updates-completely-and-for-real)

[image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot2]

Comment: unattended-upgrades are there to protect you. They shouldn't be completely disabled